# Posting a variable that is unique to a row, how do I do this?

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table, http-post

I am POSTING two things. The comment, which works ok, but the second item I need to post is the `$list['id']` that is unique to this each row. How do I include this unique id, when the user clicks POST so that it can be used on the page that it is being posted to.

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
            echo " <tr valign='top'>\n";
                            echo " <tr>$list['id']                  
                 <div class='comment_text'>
                     <form method='post' action='add_comment.php'>
                 <textarea name='comment'</textarea>
                 <input class='btn' type='submit' value='Post'/>

                 </form>
                 </div>
                 </td>\n";

            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
```

**The page I am posting to looks like this:**

```
<?php
$commenter_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$body = substr($_POST['comment'],0,400);
$post_id=;
add_comment($commenter_user_id,$post_id,$body);
$_SESSION['message'] = "Your comment has been added!";
header("Location:/social_learning/site_pages/profile.php");
?>
```

Comment: Is this existing data (like allowing a user to edit information)?

Comment: Currently i am able to post the comment, but i am not sure how to post the $list['id'] the list['id'] is the name of the post that the user will be commenting on.and i am not sure how to post it to the add_comment page, along with the comment body. that the user is also posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden input:

`<input type="hidden" name="postName" value="<?= $list['id'] ?>" />`

Then in your PHP it's available in `$_POST['postName']` (in accordance to the `name` attribute of the hidden input)